# Selenium - Error handling without throwing exception

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to Delete a object on the screen and once it's gone check if it's still in the webpage to make sure it's gone.

By doing this :

```
WebElement objectToDelete = GetElementFromDriver("object-to-delete");
objectToDelete.delete(); //in some other way which results in it being gone.
objectToDelete = GetElementFromDriver("object-to-delete");
```

I've tried surrounding it with try & catch but I keep getting an exception.
Ex:

```
try{
objectToDelete = GetElementFromDriver("object-to-delete");
} catch(Exception e){
return null;}
```

What am I missing? Is it even possible to do what I want, perhaps in a different way?

Thanks!!

If needed I'll add my chrome/driver/selenium versions although I believe they're not relevant.

Comment: What exception are you getting? Normally the global `Exception` should catch every exception.

Comment: My problem was that I got an exception instead of returning true or false

Comment: 1) We'd have to see the GetElementFromDriver code and 2) I'm 99% sure you cannot "delete" a web element using Selenium.  Perhaps it might help for us to understand why you'd want to, and we could offer an alternative strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try WebDriverWait "until" and "until_not" methods ?
Eg: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html.

Answer (score -1):

The solution -

```
public static boolean isElementPresent throws Exception(String elementName, WebElement father){
    try{
       Utils.GetElementFromElement(By.className(elementName), 5, father);
       return true;
    } catch(NoSuchElementException e){
       return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to add a secondary catch clause. NoSuchElementException is a subclass of Exception.

Comment: @Homewrecker it was needed as I did not extend Exception.
I have edited my answer to fix it :)